# vue: nuxt-i18n: Cannot translate the value of keypath

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js

I am using [nuxt-i18n](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/) to translate my page, but it can't find translation strings.

My setup:

#### nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    [
      'nuxt-i18n', {
        locales: [
          {
            code: 'en',
            name: 'English',
            iso: 'en-US',
            langFile: 'en_US.js',
          },
          {
            code: 'pt',
            name: 'Português',
            iso: 'pt-BR',
            langFile: 'pt_BR.js',
          },
        ],
        loadLanguagesAsync: true,
        langDir: 'locales/',
        defaultLocale: 'en',
      },
    ],
  ],
```

#### locales/en_US.js

```
export default {
  Greeting: 'Hello',
  Sign_up: 'Sign up',
};
```

#### file.vue

```
{{ $t('Greeting') }}
```

#### Console:

> WARN  [vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'Login'. Use
>   the value of keypath as default.

Comment: For posterity. If you do not name the locale after the locale file appropriately you can also get this message (en-us vs. en, for example)

Answer (score 13):

The solution is setting a lazy property value to true. Below is the code snippet.

```
modules: [
    [
      'nuxt-i18n', {
        lazy:true,
        locales: [
          {
            code: 'en',
            name: 'English',
            iso: 'en-US',
            langFile: 'en_US.js',
          },
          {
            code: 'pt',
            name: 'Português',
            iso: 'pt-BR',
            langFile: 'pt_BR.js',
          },
        ],
        loadLanguagesAsync: true,
        langDir: 'locales/',
        defaultLocale: 'en',
      },
    ],
  ]
```

Comment: For  "nuxt-i18n": "^6.3.0", set lazy: true, because loadLanguageAsync not exist

Comment: loadLanguagesAsync doesn't exist in my version

Answer (score 2):

The warning says it all - you don't have the *Login* message defined in the **en_US.js** file.

Somewhere in your app you're certainly calling `{{ $t('Login') }}`.

Answer (score 0):

I spent an hour only to figure out that you must not set your `langDir: 'i18n/'`. Apparently something gets messed up because the module itself is named like this too...
Renaming the folder to something else, for example "lang" fixed the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe very specific to my case, but in case this helps anyone.

My fallback locale was missing. It was defined in á .env file and fetched like so:

```
defaultLocale: process.env.FALLBACK_LOCALE,
```

I was however running the code for the first time and did not have the .env file.